# Drawing a drag and drop rectangle in react native

Tags: android, react-native

I need to create an image on my application on top of which a user can draw a rectangle to select an area of the image with its finger. I then need to obtain the the top left and bottom right coordinates of the rectangle.

I have searched the web for how to do this, but to no avail. Can anyone help?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest looking into [react-native PanResponde](https://reactnative.dev/docs/panresponder)r, or [react-native-gesture-handler PanGestureHandler.](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-gesture-handler/docs/gesture-handlers/api/pan-gh)
It is a component that responds to touch input, and calculates the x and y values when you drag your finger, it will also tell you the distance travelled from where the finger started.

You can use this data and pass the x and y travel distance back into the width and height value of a View component to make it drag out a box with your finger.

EDIT:

Here's something I just put together as a bit of an experiment using react-native-gesture-handler.

[image]

```
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { GestureEvent, PanGestureHandler, PanGestureHandlerEventPayload } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';

const Test = () => {
  const [start, setStart] = useState<{ x: number; y: number }>(null);
  const [end, setEnd] = useState<{ x: number; y: number }>({ x: 0, y: 0 });
  const [dimensions, setDimensions] = useState<{ w: number; h: number }>({ w: 0, h: 0 });

  const onPress = (event: GestureEvent<PanGestureHandlerEventPayload>) => {
    const { x, y, translationX, translationY } = event.nativeEvent;
    if (!start) setStart({ x: y, y: x });
    setDimensions({ w: translationX, h: translationY });
  };

  const onEnd = () => {
    if (!start) return;

    setEnd(start);
    setStart(null);
  };

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <PanGestureHandler onGestureEvent={onPress} onEnded={onEnd}>
        <View style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%', backgroundColor: 'red' }}>
          <View
            style={{
              position: 'absolute',
              backgroundColor: 'blue',
              top: start?.x ?? end?.x,
              left: start?.y ?? end?.y,
              width: dimensions?.w ?? 0,
              height: dimensions?.h ?? 0,
            }}
          />
        </View>
      </PanGestureHandler>
    </View>
  );
};

export default Test;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully, this one is helpful for someone. Cheers.

[image]

```
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { PanGestureHandler, PanGestureHandlerEventPayload, GestureEvent } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';


onStart = (event: GestureEvent<PanGestureHandlerEventPayload>) =>{
   const { x, y } = event.nativeEvent;
   this.setState({ startX: y, startY: x });
}

onPress = (event: GestureEvent<PanGestureHandlerEventPayload>) => {
   const { x, y, translationX, translationY } = event.nativeEvent;

   if(this.state.startX > y || this.state.startY > x){
      if(translationX < 0 && translationY < 0){
          this.setState({ startX: y });
          this.setState({ startY: x });
          this.setState({dimensionsW: translationX * -1, dimensionsH: translationY * -1})
   }else{
      if(this.state.startX > y){
          this.setState({ startX: y });
          this.setState({dimensionsH: translationY * -1, dimensionsW:translationX,})
      }
      if(this.state.startY > x){
          this.setState({ startY: x });
          this.setState({dimensionsW: translationX * -1, dimensionsH: translationY})  
      }
    }
  }else{
    if(translationX < 0 || translationY < 0 ){
        if(translationX < 0){
            this.setState({ dimensionsW:translationX * -1, dimensionsH: translationY})
        }
        if(translationY < 0){
            this.setState({ dimensionsW:translationX , dimensionsH: translationY * -1})
        }
    }else{
        this.setState({ dimensionsW:translationX, dimensionsH: translationY})
    }
  }
};

onEnd = (event: GestureEvent<PanGestureHandlerEventPayload>) => {
  const { x, y } = event.nativeEvent;
  this.setState({endX: y, endY: x});
};


<PanGestureHandler onBegan={this.onStart} onGestureEvent={this.onPress} 
onEnded={this.onEnd}>
  <View
   style={{
      position: 'absolute',
      top: this.state.startX ?? this.state.endX,
      left: this.state.startY ?? this.state.endY,
      width: this.state.dimensionsW ?? 0,
      height: this.state.dimensionsH ?? 0,
      borderColor: '#fff',
      borderWidth: 4,
      borderRadius: 15
   }}
 />
</PanGestureHandler>
```